# How to replace an object value in an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been stumped by this looking for some direction. I have a state object:

```
const state = [
{type: 'Primary', number: 123456}, 
{type: 'Mobile', number: 789012}
]
```

I have a function which is giving me the updated values for the `oldValue`, `newValue`, and `index`.

How would I be able to replace the specific `number` value for example in the 'Mobile' object and return the new array?

Comment: Do you really want to return the new array or set state with it? Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I don't think a constant can be changed after it is set: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? state[index].number = newValue

Comment: Shallow copy your `state`, using spread syntax, `.splice()` shallow copy by index inserting modified object and set state to modified array

Comment: And avoid using index to access array items - state updates are asynchronous and may be batched before execution, so if you append/delete items, you're taking the risk of modifying wrong array item. Instead, you'd better have `id` property for each object and access those items by `id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the `state` array `index` you need to change, the `newValue`and `oldValue`:

```
const newState = state.map((obj, i) => { 
  if(i === index && obj.number === oldValue) {
    let newObj = { ...obj };
    newObj.number = newValue;
    return newObj;
  }
  return obj;
}
```

Comment: just a little addition: instead of first creating a copy and then assigning `number`, you can do everything in one step: `return { ...obj, number: newValue };`

Answer (score 0):

```js
const state = [
{type: 'Primary', number: 123456}, 
{type: 'Mobile', number: 789012}
] 

const someFunction = (state, oldValue, newValue, index) => {
let newState = state.map(e => {
if(e.type === index) e.number = newValue;
return e
})
return newState
}

const newState = someFunction(state, '', 123456, 'Mobile')

console.log(newState)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to find the corresponding object and replace a specific value :

```js
const state = [
{type: 'Primary', number: 123456}, 
{type: 'Mobile', number: 789012}
]

// This will find and return the FIRST item that matches, or undefined if none are found
const ObjectToChange = state.find(elem => elem.type === 'Mobile')
if (ObjectToChange != undefined)
  ObjectToChange.number = 42;

console.log(state);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean change the value:

```js
const state = [
{type: 'Primary', number: 123456}, 
{type: 'Mobile', number: 789012}
];

state[state.findIndex(item=>item.type==='Mobile')]={type:'Mobile',number:1111}

console.log(JSON.stringify(state,null,2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Array.map` to return the updated array like so:

```js
const updateFunction = (state, oldValue, newValue, index) => {
   return state.map((stateObject, i) => i === index ? ({ ...stateObj, number: newValue }) : stateObject);
}
```